# wix4: add desktop shortcut, add link to website

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, wix4

Haven't been able to find an example of that for wix4.

I have this simple test installer which installs two text files.  What do I need to add to put a desktop link to file1.txt, and a (start menu?) link to my website?

Package.wxs:

```html
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui" 
     xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
  <Package Name="testapp" Manufacturer="TheManufacturer" Version="1.1.2.3" UpgradeCode="3e2fb354-ad90-44fd-bd9a-c51afeede2aa">
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />

    <Feature Id="Main">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExampleComponents" />
    </Feature>
      <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_InstallDir" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      </ui:WixUI>
      <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck Property="DOTNETRUNTIMECHECK" RollForward="major" RuntimeType="desktop" Version="6.0.0" Platform="x64"/>
  </Package>
</Wix>
```

and ExampleComponents.wxs:

```html
<?define RegKeyPathCU=Software\MySampleApp\TheTestApp?>

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
 xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
  <Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ExampleComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">       
      <Component Id="file1" Guid="*">
          <File Source="c:\builds\output\file1.txt" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="file2" Guid="*">
          <File Source="c:\builds\output\file2.txt" />
      </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```